# How can I add a list in a Tree`s node in Python?

Tags: python, list, avl-tree

I am trying to create a list inside this node of my AVL Tree, I also tried a function, someone has some library to import or some idea?

```
#import random, math
import re
outputdebug = False 

def debug(msg):
    if outputdebug:
    print msg

class Node():
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.left = None 
        self.right = None 
        self.list = [] #list at the node

class AVLTree():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.node = None 
        self.height = -1  
        self.balance = 0; 

    def ad_list(self, value):
        self.list.append(value) #function trying to add

    def print_list(self):
        print self.list
```

Comment: Seems you're really close. Just need to make that ad_list function a method on your Node class. See the beginning of this article: https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods

Comment: Could you double check your indentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AVLTree` class does not have a list but your `Node` class:

```
self.node.list.append(value) #function trying to add
```